# Purchases with points occupying ubercart

Tags: commerce, ubercart, payment-gateways

I want to use ubercart to create a site for online purchases but I would like to know if you can use points as a form of payment, I mean that users are placed points with which they can buy items and their points are discounted for each purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [userpoints](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [userpoints ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints_ubercart). I did this in the past using drupal7. If you want to use drupal8, you need to check if the modules have been converted.

- users can be allocated points by the admin person. the alternative is you have a product for purchasing points.
- on checkout, points is presented as a payment option.
- users can see their points balance and orders via their account page.

Another alternative is to use [commerce_userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_userpoints) with its dependent modules (commerce, userpoints). But I believe this approach has a few outstanding bugs on the issues queue.